# How to slide up and slide down with animation in android

Tags: android

I have layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_search"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fee102"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:id="@+id/search"
       android:gravity="left|center"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingTop="15dp"
       android:paddingBottom="15dp"
       android:drawablePadding="10dp"
       android:textColor="#5b5a52"
       android:text="What - When - Where?"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24px"
       android:background="#ffed64"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/what"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#5b5a52"
        android:text="What?"
        android:background="#ffed64"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/when"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#5b5a52"
        android:text="When?"
        android:background="#ffed64"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/where"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#5b5a52"
        android:text="Where?"
        android:background="#ffed64"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to slide down when search text view click and then search text view gone and all other edit text view visible with animation how to do this?

how to do in java please tell me the whole code for this

Answer (score 2):

```
public void slideUp(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            view.getHeight() ,  // fromYDelta
            0);                // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
}

public void slideDown(final View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            0,                 // fromYDelta
            view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectAnimator.

You can animate in any direction (x or y).

Android reference link
**https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html**

Answer (score 0):

make a slide_down.xml file in anim folder and copy the following code

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromYDelta="5"
    android:toYDelta="90%" />
```

for slide_up.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromYDelta="90%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

now in your java code use the following code

```
Animation slideUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_up_animation);
```

lastly cast it to your imageview or whatever u are using..

```
imageView.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation);
```